# Change the default page class in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, default

When creating a new web form the default page class is System.Web.UI.Page.  Can this default be changed in visual studio 2010 so that it uses a custom class that we created that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires editing a file within a zip.

- Open: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\1033\WebForm.zip`
- Extract and edit `default.aspx.cs`. Modify as you like!
- Save that file back into the .zip.

Repeat the same in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Cache\CSharp\Web\1033\WebForm.zip`

Any new webform items you add to projects will contain the modifications you made.

Ensure the changes are in both `ItemTemplates` and `ItemTemplatesCache`.

Comment: Remember, this changes it for **all** projects, not just the **current** project.

Comment: This worked a treat thanks!  I didn't have the ItemTemplatesCache folder, so I changed the ItemTemplates folder, and restarted visual studio and it accepted the changes.